# ERROR in resolving fallback for shared module crypto-js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, webpack-5

I have react-typescript frontend app.

I added `crypto-js` package as follow,

```
npm install crypto-js @types/crypto-js
```

Everything works fine when `mode = development` in `webpack.config.js` for development and when I run `npm run build`. Even when `mode=production`, it works fine in local machine but when I push code to gitlab and then when CI/CD runs in **Jenkins**, at one stage it runs `npm run build` command and it throws below error.

But for my QA server, I have `webpack.qa.js` as follow,

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require("webpack").container;
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");  // it uglifies the javascript files
const path = require("path");
const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
require("dotenv").config({ path: "./enviornment/.env.qa" });



module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.ts",
  mode: "production",
  cache: true,
  performance: {
    hints: false,
    maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
    maxAssetSize: 512000
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
    publicPath: "path-to"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|tsx|ts)$/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        exclude: /\.module\.css$/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|ico|svg)$/i,
        type: "asset",
        parser: {
          dataUrlCondition: {
            maxSize: 8192
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: true,
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
      extractComments: true,
      parallel: true,
      terserOptions: {
        compress: {
          drop_console: false,
        }
      }
    })],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": JSON.stringify(process.env)
    }),
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "dashboard",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {
        mfe: `mfe/remoteEntry.js`
      },
      exposes: {
        // expose each component
        "./externalApp": "./src/bootstrap"
      },
      shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: { singleton: true, eager: true, requiredVersion: deps.react },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"]
        }
      }
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

First It is taking too long compile and it fails stating

```
ERROR in resolving fallback for shared module crypto-js
```

I really have no idea what is the problem.

Also, *help me to improve the performance as it is taking too long to build it*.

Comment: Can you share you crypto-js implementation code ?
Most likely due the package you are using is not located in root `crypto-js` is causing trouble, for example using `crypto-js/sha256` would require you to  append `/` to the package name in your shared configuration `crypto-js/`

Answer (score 1):

1. Resolving `crypto-js` resolve error for shared module

- it seems that the `crypto-js` is not defined in the key `shared`
- try adding the `crypto-js` to the `shared` object, for instance:

```js
  shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: { singleton: true, eager: true, requiredVersion: deps.react },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          eager: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"]
        },
        "crypto-js": { singleton: true, eager: false, requiredVersion: deps["crypto-js"] },

      }
```

2. Improving the performance

- the `cache` accepts `boolean`, but also accepts an object that has plenty of options you can check out.
- Here's [the link to the documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/cache/#cache)
- since there will be some trade-offs for those caching options, I guess it's difficult to say confidently which one will improve the app's performance